# How to secure a Firebase Cloud Function API Rest?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to doing APIs in Firebase Cloud Functions and I need to connect my App with an ERP in such a way that the ERP can write into the node called Test in my Firebase RTDB. For this purpose I wrote the following code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');

const app = express()
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert('./credentials.json'),
    databaseURL: "https://testdb.firebaseio.com"
  });

const db = admin.database();

const endpoint = "/api/entradas";
const nodoTestDB = "test/"; 

app.post(endpoint, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db.ref(nodoTestDB + req.body.id).set({name: req.body.name });
    return res.status(204).json();    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).send(error);   
  }
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I test the function in Postman, it works fine. However, anyone could put the url in and write to the database, which is not the idea.

How can I secure the API that I create in such a way that only the ERP can access it? When I mean write securely it means:

1. That the ERP has a Token or something similar that only it knows and allows it to write to the database.
2. That only a POST type connection is allowed

I see that in the Service Account called credentials I have a private_key and a private_key_id. Would these keys serve to achieve authentication from the ERP?

Can Firebase Realtime Rules help in this case? I understand that no, because in FCF we're working with Firebase-Admin

Comment: You're going to have to define what "secure" means.  It's not a box you can simply check and have peace of mind.  Security typically has specific requirements, and also normally involves the client sending some sort of token to the backend that it can validate and check to see if the bearer of that token is allowed to do what they're requesting.

Comment: Tks @DougStevenson. I tried to specify it more deeply.

Comment: Your second requirement is already met because you're using the `post` method to define the endpoint.  Does that not work the way you expect?  The first requirement should be pretty easy to implement on your own exactly as you described - come up with a secret value, add it to the post body, and check it in your code. I suggest giving that a try and post what you have if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I understand what you are telling me about the second requirement, I am going to do tests in that sense. Regarding the first point, is it okay to make a random token that only knows the ERP and is used within the POST request without the need to do an authentication hand checking process?

Comment: If that meets your security requirements, then it's OK.

Comment: Doug is correct about using an API key or secret. That may be your simplest option if it meets your security requirements. Another option is API Gateway which is available in Google Cloud Platform. The API Gateway docs offer an option to utilize it with cloud functions like this, and you can use a service account and signed JWT. I have experimented with this in the past. It could theoretically be "more secure" but also is more complicated and less commonly utilized. https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of @Doug Stevenson and @most200, you may either use an API key or a secret value for your `POST`. In addition, you may also use [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) for your Cloud Functions and you can use a service account and signed JWT. Additional information can be found through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions).